# How to avoid margins when printing grid-like data using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, php, css, printing

What I'm trying to achieve is to print generated labels in a very fixed format. The paper they will be printed on is self-adhesive and pre-cut, so the restriction would be to print them in  exact positions on the page.

To achieve this purpose, I'm making use of the window.print() function in javascript in a separate window that contains only the grid-like structure.

The problem is that I can't seem to be able to override the margins. I would have expected top and left to be 0, but they are set to something somehow. I would like to have control over what the printable margins are.

[image: Result]

This is the most promising version I've tried:

```
@page {
   width: 210mm;
   height: 297mm;
   margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

I've also tried setting negative margins, on the `@page` element and to also wrap the divs in a parent div and set negative margins on that and they were ignored, got exactly the result in the image.

I also don't have hidden elements on the page. The window that is opened contains just a parent div with all the little rectangular divs in it.

The inner divs themselves have no margin and no margin is set up in the browser Print prompt.

I'm also open to alternatives. I was going for a front-end solution, but my backend is PHP. I wouldn't find a server-side solution adverse, but I need to make sure I will be able to have a 3 mm margin on the right, between the label and the edge of the paper.

Comment: Are you sure those margins aren't set by your printer app itself?

Comment: They might be, not really sure how to confirm. I'm not using a special app, it's just the native browser print dialog.

Comment: `print()` *(yes, you can leave off window.)* usually prompts the OS to let the Client select a printer to use. The printer settings dictate the margins. You cannot control that.

Comment: I understand. The behaviour makes perfect sense in this case. Thank you!